# Child view focus change android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ViewGroup` that can have many `LinearLayout`s. And each `LinearLayout` can have many nested child views. What I want is that, if any view(even deep nested) inside a `LinearLayout` gets focus, it should call a custom method of its main parent `LinearLayout`.

The last thing I want to do is, set `OnFocusChangeListener` on every single deep nested child views of `LinearLayout` and that listener will call its parent's custom method. But that is really bad way to go for.

Is there any method I can override of parent `LinearLayout` that gets called every time its any nested child view's focus changes ?

Comment: Hi @xmen, so what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 15):

You could use `contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener()` or override `ViewGroup.requestChildFocus()` of the root ViewGroup (`requestChildFocus()` is passed along the view parent chain).

Comment: is there a way to do this in xml?

Comment: What are you supposed to do inside your overridden `requestChildFocus()`? There is no return value..

Comment: overriding `requestChildFocus()` doesn't tell you when a child loses focus. And technically it doesn't tell you about gain of focus either, only requests.

Comment: @Trevor Since `requestChildFocus()` cannot be cancelled, there is not much of a difference.

Comment: @tmm1 Inside the overridden `requestChildFocus()` you have to call `super.requestChildFocus()`. And yes, there is no return value.