# Detect when no view is focused in Android activity

Tags: android, android-view, glsurfaceview

Is there a way to get an event in my Android activity when the focus is cleared from all views in it (ie. getCurrentFocus() will return null)?

We have an Android app that combines a GLSurfaceView with EditText objects positioned on top of it (not as children, that's not possible). At some point, clearFocus() is called on the EditText, so focus is removed from it. The focus is not given to our surface view.

```
FrameLayout - not focusable
  - GLSurfaceView (regular rendering view) - focusable
  - RelativeLayout 
    - EditText - focusable
```

clearFocus() will try to set focus to the first focusable view, but it doesn't find our GLSurfaceView, I guess because its a sibling not a parent.

So we end up with nothing focussed. I would like to detect this situation, without having to add code to every possible case that causes it.

Comment: Not really expecting this is possible, actually, and that I will have to go and find all the cases where clearFocus is called :)

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185136/child-view-focus-change-android

Comment: addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener looks pretty promising, I think you could put this is an answer. Will try anyway

Comment: @Rediska thank you, this works in a nice general way! I just get my rootView and observe focus changes in it's tree. If you make an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Well, that wasn't my answer, but I am glad it works for you.